# Get the "plain" (end-user readable) name of UWP apps installed on a system

Tags: powershell, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm using the following PowerShell script to retrieve and save to a text file the list of UWP apps on a system. It gets the ID, name (system name) and packagefamilyname.

In addition to the name, I'm looking for a way to retrieve the plain name of the app: for example, "OneNote" instead of "Microsoft.Office.OneNote". Ideally, this name would also be localized: for example, "Calculatrice" (on a French system) instead of "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator".

I found this [list of info retrieved by Get-AppxPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sccm/protect/deploy-use/find-a-pfn-for-per-app-vpn) but nothing like an end-user readable name... I'm not very familiar this area of expertise. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$installedapps = get-AppxPackage
$ids = $null

foreach ($app in $installedapps)
{
  try
  {
    $ids = (Get-AppxPackageManifest $app -erroraction Stop).package.applications.application.id
  }
  catch
  {
    Write-Output "No Id's found for $($app.name)" 
  }
  foreach ($id in $ids)
  {
    $line = $app.Name + "`t" + $app.packagefamilyname + "!" + $id
    echo $line
    $line >> 'c:\temp\output.txt'
  }
}
write-host "Press any key to continue..."
[void][System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Completed updated]

You can do this pretty easily in C#. You have to reference the correct WinMDs from the Windows SDK (the actual directories will change depending on SDK version):

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\6.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd`

If you can't build a stand-alone EXE and just want pure PowerShell, you *might* be able to reference the WinMDs `%systemroot%\system32\winmetadata`. The code is pretty simple (I avoided `await` since I don't know if PowerShell has that):

```
// using Windows.Management.Deployment;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetList();
}

static void GetList()
{
    var pm = new PackageManager();
    var packages = pm.FindPackagesForUser("");
    foreach (var package in packages)
    {
        var asyncResult = package.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
        while (asyncResult.Status != Windows.Foundation.AsyncStatus.Completed)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }

        foreach (var app in asyncResult.GetResults())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(app.DisplayInfo.DisplayName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter for these detailed instructions. I was able to execute manually steps 1 to 4. At step 5, PowerShell does not recognize the "makepri" command. It says (in French): "makepri : Le terme «makepri» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande, ...". Maybe there is something not installed on my system?

Comment: This being said, I see how I can get the info manually on my system. But scripting this to run an any user's system seems to be quite a big challenge...

Comment: `makepri` is part of the Windows SDK. I replaced the answer with a much simpler programmatic solution that won't require the Windows SDK on each machine, but I don't know if you can PowerShell-ize.

Comment: Thanks again Peter. Reading your code, I see it does what I need. But I do not have SDK nor C# dev tools. I'm using AutoHotkey + PowerShell (AHK alone could not retrieve these infos about installed Windows Apps). I'm pretty confortable with AHK but not much in PS scripting yet. If one could see how Peter's C# code could be converted to PowerShell?

Comment: I don't have to tools to make an .EXE from your C# code. I'm using the PowerShell script from an AutoHotkey app that is parsing the text file created by the PS script. I did some research on PowerShell scripting (quite new for me) and on the commands you use in your C# code. My first impression is that these commands could not be ported easily to PS.  I'll "accept" your answer because it really helps. Later, I will need to do more research and ask for more help to make it work under PowerShell. But, for now, I will have to stay with these "system names" in my app.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time looking for this today, and finally came up with a solution that doesn't involve a page of code, or digging around in files/registry/etc.  Put the below two lines in a script or function, and it will return PoSh-friendly output which you can then pipe into ForEach-Object, Where-Object, Sort-Object, Export-CSV, etc.

```
$PkgMgr = [Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager,Windows.Web,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]::new()

$PkgMgr.FindPackages() | Select-Object DisplayName -ExpandProperty Id
```

The [.FindPackages()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackages?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Management_Deployment_PackageManager_FindPackages_System_String_) method also has an overload which takes a Family Name, but the docs lead me to believe it can only accept exact names, not wildcard matches.  So unless you know ***exactly*** what you are looking for, I am guessing it is best to retrieve the list of all packages, and then do your own searches on that list.

The docs do say that this will return packages for all users, and that it requires admin/elevated rights to run.